# Get data with 1 query from 4 tables

Tags: mysql

I have the following tables:

```
interests
interests_statuses
users_interests
interests
```

A user can have a interest, based on the interest he follows, I need to get the statuses posted in the interests.

I don't know how to properly display my tables, so you can understand the relation in all tables, but I will show you a query I tried the below query, that is not working:

```
SELECT s.*, i.*, i_s.*, u_s.*
FROM statuses s, interests i, interests_statuses i_s, users_interests u_s
WHERE u_s.user_id = '3' AND u_s.interest_id = i.id AND i_s.status_id = s.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use JOINS explicitly like

```
SELECT s.*, i.*, i_s.*, u_s.* 
FROM statuses s INNER JOIN interests i ON s.id = i.id
INNER JOIN interests_statuses i_s ON i_s.interest_id = i.id
INNER JOIN users_interests u_s ON u_s.interest_id = i.id
WHERE u_s.user_id = '3' AND i_s.status_id = s.id
```

Comment: The issue I had here was that I had to join two tables at one point. For example:

I need to get all statuses, so I start with that table. Then I join interests_statuses, because I need to get the ID's of the interests that are bounded to the status. Then I need to join interests to get all interests availble, and users_interests to get the user to interest relation.

Comment: why repeating `on u_s.interest_id = i.id`? ... ok... i see now - a typo